# QueryDSL with OR operator instead of AND

Tags: java, spring, rest, predicate, querydsl

I need some help with the QueryDSL lib. More specifically i have this:

I am trying to make an search endpoint that will enable the user to search for saved items with specific features like name, location, owner etc.. ( the searchable fields are class variables )

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
PagedResources<SavedItemResource> searchByQuery(final Pageable pageable,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) final List<String> typeFilters,
                                                    @QuerydslPredicate(root = SavedItem.class) Predicate predicate) {
   return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(service.findAll(predicate,pageable), assembler);
}
```

I customized the binding like this to support list of values for each field.

```
 MultiValueBinding<StringPath, String> contains = (path, values) -> {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        for (String value : values) {
            predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
        }
        return predicate;
    };
```

This works very well if i only search on one field. But when I search on multiple fields it does not work because the @QuerydslPredicate will make a predicate with a AND operator. But i need an OR between the different fields.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thx in advance!

Comment: I gave this up.. i just wrote a query myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to create a new predicate replacing AND operator for OR:

```
 public static Predicate replaceAndForOR(Predicate predicate) {
    if (predicate instanceof PredicateOperation) {
      PredicateOperation operation = (PredicateOperation) predicate;
      List<Expression<?>> expressions = operation.getArgs();
      BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

      for (Expression<?> exp : expressions) {
        String[] expStrings = exp.toString().split("&&");
        PredicateOperation op = (PredicateOperation) exp;

        if (expStrings.length > 1) {
          Predicate p = replaceAndForOR(op);
          builder.or(p);
        } else {
          builder.or(op);
        }
      }

      return builder.getValue();
    } else {
      return predicate;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I voted up. I think you should reformat the code. one closing bracket is missing.